# Changing style of only one button with the same class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 7 like buttons with the same class:

```
<button class="like" onclick="like()"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
```

Now i want to change only this button which is clicked, but it is chaning all 7 colors:

```
function like() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("fa-thumbs-up");
  for (let element of elements) {
    element.style.color = "orange";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** You can pass the reference of the `button` to the `like` as

```
onclick="like(this)"
```

and change the color of that particular HTML element as:

```
e.style.color = "orange";
```

```js
function like(e) {
  e.style.color = "orange";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<button class="like" onclick="like(this)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like" onclick="like(this)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like" onclick="like(this)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like" onclick="like(this)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like" onclick="like(this)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like" onclick="like(this)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like" onclick="like(this)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
```

**2)** **`Recommended approach`**

It would be better to select all buttons using `querySelectorAll` in JS and add event listener on it.

```js
function like(e) {
  e.target.style.color = "orange";
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button.like");
buttons.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", like)
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let closest = e.target.closest('.like')
  if(closest) closest.style.color = "orange"
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve the anwser from @decpk you shouldnt use `.style` in 2021 anymore. Use `classList` instead to apply chanegs through CSS. Espacially using `.toggle`makes it easier not only to change the coor but also revert it.

```js
function like(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('color-orange');
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button.like");
buttons.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", like)
});
```

```css
.color-orange {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
<button class="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` to apply just to the current element like the following example:

```
<button class="like" onclick="like(this)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
```

And to get the element inside the current element just use `querySelector` in your Javascript code like this:

```
function like(element){
            var  currentThumbs = element.querySelector('.fa-thumbs-up');
            currentThumbs.style.color = "orange";
}
```